# SELECT IF into custom variable

Tags: sql-server

I have this:

```
SELECT 
        @is_daily_rollup = CASE WHEN rt.[id]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0,
        @is_weekly_rollup = CASE WHEN rt.[id]=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0
```

But sql server is complaining about syntax.  How would I go about implementing this conditional value into a variable?

Comment: If that's a table alias, you need to reference the table. Also, does your table only contain one row? else, the above logic fails!

Comment: I'm limiting it to one row in my where clause; was too lazy to paste the whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a `CASE` statement you need to provide an `END`

```
CASE WHEN rt.[id]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
CASE WHEN rt.[id]=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

so your full query would be:

```
SELECT @is_daily_rollup = CASE WHEN rt.[id]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       @is_weekly_rollup = CASE WHEN rt.[id]=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `END` for your `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
        @is_daily_rollup = CASE WHEN rt.[id]=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        @is_weekly_rollup = CASE WHEN rt.[id]=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Of course, this is assuming that you already declared yor variables.